# Query Notification for SQL Server - alternatives?

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008

Are there any alternatives to query notification for SQL Server?

I have a desktop application in windows forms (1000+ clients) and SQL Server 2008 database on the server. In my case there are many tables with client-specific data (20+ tables), so I have to notify the user when a value has changed meanwhile.

I solved the problem with Query Notification ([here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/144344/Query-Notification-using-SqlDependency-and-SqlCach)) and it worked very well for my test case. Though for me this solution doesn't look like the best one for my scenario with that many clients, because I think it would be a lot of database traffic and I have to deal with a large number of entries in the `sys.dm_qn_subscriptions` table.

Comment: Personally - I'd consider making a middle tier between the SQL Server and your clients that willl be notified by the server and then handle the responsibility of notifying your clients, which then can use various different forms of messaging techniques. This way only one app needs to be notified by SQL Server and thereby limit your subscriptions